# Oracle 11G and Toad

Tags: oracle11g, toad

I installed trail version of Oracle 11g 64 bit on my laptop. I installed Oracle 10.6.1.3
and it is giving me an error saying Oracle 32 bit database not found?

I am new to Oracle and wondering whether there is a 64bit Toad? Also if Toad doesn't work what should I do to learn Oracle with the installed 11G version is there a different IDE.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11183826/109702) on another Stack Overflow question. You actually most likely need to install the 32 bit on your machine. Sounds weird I know, according to Toad support only 32 bit is supported now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Oracle SQL Developer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index-098778.html

There are Win-32, Win-64, Linux, and Mac OS X versions available.